# Magento2 - Translate title property in knockout js html template

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, html, translate

I have `href` html tag that looks like this in my knockout html template

```
  <a data-fancybox data-src="#price_policy" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Shipping Cost" data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping will be available in your area'"> </a>
```

this html tag has `title` property that i need to translate, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way ..

```
<a data-fancybox data-src="#price_policy" href="javascript:void(0);" attr: {title: i18n:'Shipping Cost'} data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping will be available in your area'"> </a>
```

Comment: i'm doing this in knockout template not in phtml

Comment: @jojo i have updated my answer

Comment: @RakeshDongan the title doesnt appear when i hover the element